# Encountering error with float in C++ (trying to call from array?)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm very confused on how I should be writing my code to call for a highest balance among my users in a program and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am using VS studio on a mac.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct userAccount {
    // struct to store user info
    std::string username;
    int age;
    std::string nationality;
    int account_balance;
};

int main() {
// create array of user struct up to 20 accs
userAccount accts[20];

// instructions for user
cout << "Enter name, age, nationality, and balance separating with space:" << endl;

// read data inputted into struct
string username;
int age;
int count = 0;
int userCount = 0;
string nationality;
float account_balance;
while (cin >> username >> age >> nationality >> account_balance) {
    userAccount user;
    user.username = username;
    user.age = age;
    user.nationality = nationality;
    user.account_balance = account_balance;
    accts[count] = user;
    count++;    
}

//find account with highest balance
float highestBalance = 0.0; 
for (int i = 0; i < userAccount; i++) {
    if (account_balance > highestBalance)
        highestBalance = account_balance;    
} 

cout << "The highest balance out of everyone is: $" << highestBalance << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The error I'm receiving from VS studio:

```
    project1try3.cpp:46:32: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
for (int i = 0; i < userAccount; i++) {
```

(user account has a squiggly line underneath)

I tried putting userAccount into parentheses based off of the error:

```
 //find account with highest balance
    float highestBalance = 0.0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < (userAccount); i++) {
        if (account_balance > highestBalance)
        highestBalance = account_balance;
}
```

and then I received an error stating:

```
    project1try3.cpp:46:34: error: expected expression
for (int i = 0; i < (userAccount); i++)
```

(then a carrot is put under the ";" after (userAccount).

I was hoping someone could provide feedback on what the issue might be here and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect with the `i < userAccount` while `userAccount` is a type, but not a variable?

Comment: `userAccount` is NOT an `int` so you can't compare them. Also do not use that "C" style array for accounts, use `std::vector<userAccount> accts;` (this is C++ after all not "C"). And learn to write code without global variables.

Comment: `userAccount` is the type of the structure. Perhaps you're supposed to use `count`? And use the value from `acct[i].account_balance`?

Comment: `userAccount` should be `count`. (There is also an unused `userCount`. Did you let autocompletion write "userAccount"?)

Comment: This is a classic case where the description of the error is leading you down the wrong path. The real error is 'i < userAccount' makes no sense. A number (say 7) can't be compared to an abstract type (not even an instance but the type itself. But the compiler is guessing because that you've got looks a bit like something called a function-style cast. So its guess is you were doing that. You aren't.

Answer (score 3):

According to the comment, `//find account with highest balance`, you try to find the account with the highest balance here:

```cpp
float highestBalance = 0.0; 
for (int i = 0; i < userAccount; i++) {
    if (account_balance > highestBalance)
        highestBalance = account_balance;
    
}
```

It has four faults:

1. The `account_balance` member is an `int` but `highestBalance` is a `float` for no good reason. Make that an `int` too.
2. It uses the *type* `userAccount` as a variable and tries to compare that to `i`. It would be similar to doing `i < int`. It doesn't make sense. The only variable you have which carries information about how many accounts there are is `count`, so you need to change the loop:

   ```cpp
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   ```
3. You don't actually compare `highestBalance` with the balance of the user in `accts[i]` so that needs to be changed too:

   ```cpp
       if (accts[i].account_balance > highestBalance)
           highestBalance = accts[i].account_balance;
   ```
4. You've now found the highest balance, but not *the account* with the highest balance, which is what your comment said you should find. Adapted to find the account:

   ```cpp
   std::size_t hb = 0;
   for (std::size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
       if (accts[i].account_balance > accts[hb].account_balance)
           hb = i;
   }
   ```

   `accts[hb]` will now be the account with the highest balance.